# Anybody knows how to solve this error?

Tags: c++

OLSR class file
  OLSR.cc

```
OLSR::link_sensing
(OLSR_msg& msg, const nsaddr_t &receiver_iface, const nsaddr_t &sender_iface, const int &index)

{
OLSR_hello& hello = msg.hello();
double now = CURRENT_TIME;
bool updated = false;
bool created = false;

OLSR_link_tuple* link_tuple = state_.find_link_tuple(sender_iface);
if (link_tuple == NULL)
{
    // We have to create a new tuple
    link_tuple = new OLSR_link_tuple;
    link_tuple->nb_iface_addr() = sender_iface;
    link_tuple->local_iface_addr() = receiver_iface;

    //For testing only
    if(sender_iface == 168427530 && receiver_iface == 169082900 ) //Error occur at this line
    {
        link_tuple->link_quality_metric() = 0.9;
    }
```

OLSR header file
    OLSR.h

```
virtual bool        link_sensing(OLSR_msg&, const nsaddr_t &, const nsaddr_t &, const int &);
```

error get: Description
no match for 'operator==' in 'receiver_iface == 169082900'

Comment: @MartinDrozdik It's a class that's either omits or incorrectly declares the the equality operator.

Comment: Can you think of a more descriptive title?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear.

> no match for 'operator==' in 'receiver_iface == 169082900'

means, the compiler does not understand what you mean by `==` in

```
receiver_iface == 169082900
```

That is, it does not know how to compare `receiver_iface` and `169082900`.

`receiver_iface` is of type `nsaddr_t` (whatever that is) and `169082900` is of type `int`.

So you should define the following function before the code that causes the error:

```
bool operator== (const nsaddr_t &left, int right)
{
    // whatever you consider appropriate
}
```

Comment: That's one way to do it -- or maybe comparing something of type `nsaddr_t` to an integer isn't a good idea.